# Certificate Authentication not working in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl, certificate

I am trying to implement Certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core 5.0. I created an API method that will be authenticated wtih Root CA and Child Certificate. I am following the official docs for it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0

There are 2 projects one is a web api project (that requires certificated) other is client project which has to call the web api project to fetch data from api.

The Web API Project code is as follows:

1. HomeController.cs

   ```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Reservation> Get()
        {
            return new List<Reservation> {
                new Reservation {Id=1, Name = "Ankit", StartLocation = "New York", EndLocation="Beijing" },
                new Reservation {Id=2, Name = "Bobby", StartLocation = "New Jersey", EndLocation="Boston" },
                new Reservation { Id = 3, Name = "Jacky", StartLocation = "London", EndLocation = "Paris" }
                };
        }
     }
   ```
2. Startup.cs

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }   

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication(
            CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(options =>
            {
                options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyCertificateValidationService>();

                        if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                        {
                            context.Success();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Fail("invalid cert");
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Fail("invalid cert");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCertificateForwarding();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }}
   ```

In the above code I have configured certificate authentication inside the `ConfigureServices()` method.

3. MyCertificateValidationService.cs

This class check the client certificate thumbprint.

```
public class MyCertificateValidationService
{
public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
{
    return CheckIfThumbprintIsValid(clientCertificate);
}

private bool CheckIfThumbprintIsValid(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
{
    var listOfValidThumbprints = new List<string>
    {
        "D8BF2DB9766110BF3768C18E39ECE19EA746342A"
    };

    if (listOfValidThumbprints.Contains(clientCertificate.Thumbprint))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}}
```

4. Program.cs

Here I have configured Kestrel

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                        o.ClientCertificateMode =
                            ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
                });
            });
}
```

Next, on the client project the code which calls the API is given as follows:

```
private async Task<JsonDocument> GetApiDataUsingHttpClientHandler()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44392/api/Home"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    };
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
        return data;
    }

    throw new ApplicationException($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
}
```

I always get "ApplicationException: Status code: Forbidden, Error: Forbidden" error on the client project. It seems some problem which I am not able to find out. The error screenshot is given below:
[image]

If I remove the [Authorize] attribute from the web api controller then it works fine. This proves certificate authentication is not working at all. What can be the problem?

Note that I created 2 certificates in powershell. One is root ca which I imported to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

other is client certificate which is imported to Personal folder through Cert manager.

Comment: Could u try to change thee order in your Configure method of your Startup.cs to the following: UseAuthentication(), UseRouting(), UseAuthorization(), UseEndpoints()

Comment: I checked it just now, same error - "ApplicationException: Status code: Forbidden, Error: Forbidden".

Comment: Did you check, that the certificate validation is called?

Comment: How should I check it, the breakpoints are not reached?

Comment: Am facing similar problem? @yogihosting, did you managed to resolve this problem yet?

Comment: @Jagankumar yes I found the solution. Check this working example [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/certificate-authentication/).

Comment: @yogihosting, sorry I could not find anything different from your above code in the provided link. Also some people commented that they got similar 403 forbidden error as mine. When I checked the detailed log, following messages

Comment: Request matched endpoint 'NewApi.Controllers.TestController.Post (NewApi)'  -> No client certificate found. -> AuthenticationScheme: Certificate was not authenticated. -> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user. -> AuthenticationScheme: Certificate was challenged. ->Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44398/api/test/ - 0 - 403

Comment: @Jagankumar check the link i gave to you. Download the source codes and run it as the tutorial in the link says.

Comment: Thanks @yogihosting, found my issue is with the IIS express setting, was missing the below 2 settings. applicationhost.config file: Set <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" /> and <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>. After corrected it is working like charm. Thanks for your help